# Traversing Each table row and adding hyperlink to it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink, datatables

My Table is getting dynamically generated through `Jquery DataTable`. Which looks something like this:

```
<table id ="mySearchResults">
    <tr>
        <td>MyName</td>
        <td>MyPlace</td>
        <td>Status</td>
    <tr>
    <tr>
        <td>MyName1</td>
        <td>MyPlace1</td>
        <td>Status1</td>
    <tr>
</table>
```

I want to traverse the whole table but only want to check 2nd or some other column value (consider this table to be quiet big, so I want to access by index). If its value corresponds to something, then I would like to add a hyperlink to the whole row which calls a Jquery function, where I can access all the values of that particular row.

I tried something like, It doesn't seem to be working. Any inputs appreciated.

```
$('#mySearchResultstr').each(function() {
    var value = $(this).find('td 6').val();   //Consider 6 to 6th column
    if(value='abc'){                          //Check if it is abc
        $(this).parent.add                    //Not sure what function to call to add hyperlink to a local jquery function. 
    } 
});
```

Btw. my rows can not have an anchor tag by default. Only based on value of certain column, it should have hyperlink.

Also how can I make sure, this traversing happens once the table is loaded, since the table is loaded via AJAX.

Comment: Did you got it working ?

Comment: Yes Prakash. Thanks, your code was good. I avoided alot of unnecessary JavaScript code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well instead of traversing each table row separately you can take advantage of `"createdRow"` parameter of `DataTable`.

At the time of table creation you can check the values of the required column and assign the respective function as link to that row as below

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/Prakash_Thete/xck2jys3/5/

Example taken for demonstration in Fiddle :

```
//HTML
<table id="item" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
      <thead>
           <tr>
               <th>Name</th>
               <th>Age</th>
               <th>Start date</th>
               <th>Salary</th>
           </tr>
       </thead>
</table>


//JS

var tableData = [
        [   "Tiger Nixon",
            "61",
            "2011/04/25",
            "$320,800"
        ],
        [
           "Garrett Winters",
           "63",
           "2011/07/25",
           "$170,750"
        ],
       [
         "Ashton Cox",
         "66",
         "2009/01/12",
         "$86,000"
       ]
   ]; 

var itemTable = $("#item").DataTable({
     "data":tableData,
     "createdRow": function ( row, data, index ) {

       // you can check value of the any column you want 
       // I have checked the "age" column value
       if(data[1] > 62){
            $(row).attr("data-href", "greaterThanSixtyTwo");
       } else {
            $(row).attr("data-href", "lessThanSixtyTwo");
       }
    }
});   

//click event handler for row 
$('#item tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
    //fetch the row data
    var rowData = itemTable.row( this ).data();

    //fetch the function to be called on click of this row
    var functionToCall = $(this).data("href");

    //call the function with clicked rows data 
    eval( functionToCall + "( '"+rowData +"' )" );
});

function greaterThanSixtyTwo(rowData){
  console.log(" I am greater than Sixty Two - > : ", rowData);
}

function lessThanSixtyTwo(rowData){
  console.log("I am less than Sixty Two - > : ", rowData);
}
```

Comment: Very clean code. Works well with my current data table implementation. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You most likely want to use [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) or [`.prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) methods of jQuery element:

```
// Iterating over <tr> elements, which are descendants of your table
$("#mySearchResultstr tr").each(function () {
    // $thisRow will contain a reference to a <tr> element
    // wrapped in jQuery Object
    var $thisRow = $(this);

    if (YOUR_CONDITION_HERE) {
        // Create new Link
        var $link = $("<a/>");
        $link.attr("href", YOUR_URL);
        $link.text("SOMETHING");

        // Use append or prepend, depends on where you want to insert the link
        $thisRow.append($link);
    }
});
```

Comment: just a clarification. Does this append a new row OR new cell OR just makes the current row clickable?

Comment: The end result would be something like this: ``<td>Status<a href="YOUR_URL">SOMETHING</a></td>`` (I've added the SOMETHING part to the answer).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I had slightly different requirement though.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("tr").each(function(){

        var href = "yourHref";
        var name = "your name";

        var value  = $("td",this).eq(5).text();

        if(value == 'abc') {
            $(this).html("<td colspan=6><a href=" + href + ">" + name + "</a></td>" );
        }

    })

})
```

Final code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
       <table border="1">
           <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr>
           <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>abc</td></tr>
           <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr>
           <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>abc</td></tr>
        </table>
  

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    $("tr").each(function(){
        
        var href = "yourHref";
        var name = "your name";
        
        var value  = $("td",this).eq(5).text();

        if(value == 'abc') {
            $(this).html("<td colspan=6><a href=" + href + ">" + name + "</a></td>" );
        }
        
    })
    
})
        
            
        </script>
    </body>  
</html>
```

Comment: I do not need to add a new element which is hyperlink. Rather I want the whole row to be hyperlinked to something.

Comment: @Crawling , i update post. see it ,if help you mark my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Your solution works. But I had slightly different requirements. learnt few things. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

### Description

1. Delegate click event to `#btn`
2. `content` is whatever is entered in #in1
     To be matched with `#result`'s `<td>` content
3. `url` is an address entered in `#in2`
4. If user did not enter a url, the default
     will be used: `http://www.example.com`
5. Next, each `<td>` will be searched to see
     if any content entered by user is matched
     with the content of each `<td>`
6. Any `<td>` that is matched, will have it's 
     text wrapped in a dynamically created
     anchor which will include a predetermined
     url (by user input or default see #3 and #4).
7. ✎ On each `<td>` we will do the
     following:

   - Collect all siblings name them
      `$sisters`.
   - On `$sisters` change the background
     to yellow.
   - Find parent `<tr>` and assign it
      as `$mom`.
   - Each `$mom` will get an `id = "row" + idx`.
      `idx` corresponds to `<td>` index 
      position within the table (0 zero count).
      Use devtools to inspect the `<tr>` to
      see what I'm talking about.

✎ Upon further reading of OP's request I have improved my answer to include `<tr>` and sibling `<td>` manipulation. Also, the default url function has been disabled see #4 and source for details.

---

### References

- [`wrapInner()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapinner/)
- [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)
- [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)

---

### Examples

**[<kbd>PLUNKER</kbd>](http://embed.plnkr.co/geWo72XvDYDoYQBuMQFV/)**

#### SNIPPET

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <style>
    body {
      font: 400 16px/1.428 Consolas;
    }
    #results {
      border: 2px solid grey;
    }
    td {
      border: 1px solid black;
      padding: 5px;
    }
    a {
      color: yellow;
      background: #000;
      display: inline;
      transition: all 1s;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    a:hover {
      color: #000;
      background: yellow;
      display: block;
      transition: all 1s;
      text-decoration: underline;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Query Content</legend>
    <input id='in1' type='search' placeholder='LOC5' search='5'>
    <button id='btn1'>Search</button>
    <input id='in2' placeholder='http://google.com'>
    <br/>
    <small>Search function is case-sensitive</small>
  </fieldset>

  <table id="results">
    <tr>
      <td>NAME4</td>
      <td>LOC4</td>
      <td>STATUS4</td>
      <td>NAME1</td>
      <td>LOC1</td>
      <td>STATUS1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>NAME4</td>
      <td>LOC4</td>
      <td>STATUS4</td>
      <td>NAME2</td>
      <td>LOC2</td>
      <td>STATUS2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>NAME3</td>
      <td>LOC3</td>
      <td>STATUS3</td>
      <td>NAME2</td>
      <td>LOC2</td>
      <td>STATUS2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>NAME4</td>
      <td>LOC4</td>
      <td>STATUS4</td>
      <td>NAME1</td>
      <td>LOC1</td>
      <td>STATUS1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>NAME5</td>
      <td>LOC5</td>
      <td>STATUS5</td>
      <td>NAME2</td>
      <td>LOC2</td>
      <td>STATUS2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>NAME5</td>
      <td>LOC5</td>
      <td>STATUS5</td>
      <td>NAME1</td>
      <td>LOC1</td>
      <td>STATUS1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>NAME4</td>
      <td>LOC4</td>
      <td>STATUS4</td>
      <td>NAME2</td>
      <td>LOC2</td>
      <td>STATUS2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>NAME3</td>
      <td>LOC3</td>
      <td>STATUS3</td>
      <td>NAME1</td>
      <td>LOC1</td>
      <td>STATUS1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>NAME2</td>
      <td>LOC2</td>
      <td>STATUS2</td>
      <td>NAME4</td>
      <td>LOC4</td>
      <td>STATUS4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>NAME5</td>
      <td>LOC5</td>
      <td>STATUS5</td>
      <td>NAME3</td>
      <td>LOC3</td>
      <td>STATUS3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>NAME1</td>
      <td>LOC1</td>
      <td>STATUS1</td>
      <td>NAME5</td>
      <td>LOC5</td>
      <td>STATUS5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>NAME2</td>
      <td>LOC2</td>
      <td>STATUS2</td>
      <td>NAME1</td>
      <td>LOC1</td>
      <td>STATUS1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>NAME3</td>
      <td>LOC3</td>
      <td>STATUS3</td>
      <td>NAME5</td>
      <td>LOC5</td>
      <td>STATUS5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>NAME4</td>
      <td>LOC4</td>
      <td>STATUS4</td>
      <td>NAME1</td>
      <td>LOC1</td>
      <td>STATUS1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>NAME5</td>
      <td>LOC5</td>
      <td>STATUS5</td>
      <td>NAME3</td>
      <td>LOC3</td>
      <td>STATUS3</td>
    </tr>

  </table>


  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    /*
       | 1. Delegate click event to #btn
       | 2. content is whatever is entered in #in1
       |    To be matched with #result's <td> content
       | 3. url is an address entered in #in2
       | 4.✎ If user did not enter a url, the default
       |    will be used: http://www.example.com
       | 5. Next, each <td> will be searched to see
       |    if any content entered by user is matched
       |    with the content of each <td>
       | 6. Any <td> that is matched, will have it's 
       |    text wrapped in a dynamically created
       |    anchor which will include a predetermined
       |    url (by user input or default see #3 and #4
       */

    $('#btn1').on('click', function() {

      var content = $('#in1').val();
      var url = $('#in2').val();
      
      /* Uncomment if default url is desired 
      if (url === 'undefined' || url === null || url === '') {
        url = 'http://www.example.com';
      }
      */

      /*
      | 7. On each `<td>` we will do the
      |    following:
      |    a. Collect all siblings name them
      |       $sisters.
      |    b. On $sisters change the background
      |       to yellow.
      |    c. Find parent `<tr>` and assign it
      |       as $mom.
      |    d. Each $mom will get an id='row'+idx.
      |       idx corresponds to `<td>` index 
      |       position within the table (0 zero count).
      |       Use devtools to inspect the `<tr>` to
      |       see what I'm talking about.
      */


      $('td').each(function(idx) {

        var $sisters = $(this).siblings();
        var $mom = $(this).parent();

        if ($(this).text() === content) {
          $(this).wrapInner('<a href="' + url + '"></a>');

          $sisters.css('background', 'yellow');

          $mom.each(function() {
            $(this).attr('id', 'row' + idx);
          });
        }
      });

    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply. Very informative!